# How to stub whole module using Mocha?

Tags: ruby, unit-testing

I have a complex module used in my implementation with some functions in it.

```
module A
  def function some_params
    #returns some chain object
  end
end

#implementation

class SomeImplementation
  def some_function some_params
    A.function(some_params_other).function1 
  end
end
```

I want to stub it by my class:

```
class AStub
  def function params
    #rely on params
    do_something_else_return_same_object
  end

  def function1
    other_do
  end
end
```

How i can do it? In particular **how to replace A to being my class using Mocha**. Any thoughts? I can't do that:

```
A.stubs(:function)
```

because there is no way to catch first parameters (i need them to define next behavior).

Answer (score 2):

To answer your question, here's how to do it (from the docs and from what I understand of your problem, so I might have it wrong):

```
A.expects(:function).with(<some params>).returns(AStub)
A.expects(:function).with(<some other params>).returns(AnotherStub)
```

---

But IMHO, I think it really boils down to how you want to design you code.

You basically want to have `A` replaced by a mock for your tests but you could actually have it "injected" using other techniques (and then use mocha traditionally).

Here are some techniques I would use:

**1. Pass the module specifically to that method using a default parameter:**

```
class SomeImplementation
  def some_function <some_params>, a_obj = A
    a_obj.function(some_params_other).function1 
  end
end
```

So that you would need do something like

```
SomeImplementation.new.some_function(some_params, your_test_double_for(A))
```

**2. Pass the module for the whole object:**

```
class SomeImplementation
  def initialize(some_obj_params, a_obj = A)
    @a_obj = a_obj
  end

  def some_function some_params
    @a_obj.function(some_params_other).function1 
  end
end
```

In that case you'd write:

```
SomeImplementation.new(your_test_double_for(A)).some_function(some_params)`
```

Also, when given the choice, I avoid using modules as they're harder to work with when you're "really" using TDD (by "really" I just mean "discovering the emergent design while you code).